# Weird typo in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos

I am having some issues regarding Visual Studio Code. I was writing code and suddenly, the syntax went into some kind of "insert" mode. It shows up a weird white box. I am on a Macbook so I don't know what I pressed. Here's the screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL4rw.png)
It shows up in every file in all my folders.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you activated the insert function on your keyboard, which is done (and can be undone) by this hotkey:

`fn` + `return`

`fn` can be found at the bottom left of a standard mac keyboard, `return` at the centre right.